# Executing testcases from jenkins and getting error

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

We have automated few test cases and trying to execute the same test cases from jenkins and getting below error:

```
+ pybot -x junit.xml run.robot
==============================================================================
Run                                                                           
==============================================================================
sip-001                                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sip-002                                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Run                                                                   | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed


Output:  /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/integration-test/workspace/output.xml
[ ERROR ] Reading XML source '/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/integration-test/workspace/output.xml' failed: ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

Here Testcases are passed but results junit.xml are not generating.

The same testcases if we execute from Ubuntu machine. /path/run.robot .
The Testcases are passed and results are generating like junit.xml, output.xml etc..

Manually testcases are executing fine and results are generating.

Can anyone please guide me in resolving the above error which we got while executing from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin robotframework plugin to display results in Jenkins.

Answer (score -2):

WORKAROUND: This won't help you keep using Jenkins, but I had a similar issue with Test Cases running fine when I executed them manually from the command prompt on Windows or running Robot Framework in Eclipse. When running in Jenkins I got failures and never was able to get an answer from anyone, anywhere. I finally just dumped Jenkins all together and set up a Windows Task Manager to have the Robot Framework test case run from there instead. I'll continue using that until someone gets me a real fix or answer that I can actually implement. By the way: Thanks for the negative! Keep them coming.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a useful answer.